# How to write a List<String[]> in a csv file with simpleflatmapper?

Tags: java, csv, simpleflatmapper

I must use the library **[simpleflatmapper](http://simpleflatmapper.org/0101-getting-started-csv.html)** and I can't find a way to simply write in a **csv file** a `List<String[]>` with this **library**. I can parse (without blankline) and stock in a `List<String[]>` :

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("file.csv");
Iterator<String[]> parser = CsvParser.separator(',').quote('\"').iterator(file);
List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] line;
while(parser.hasNext()) {
    line = parser.next();
    if (line[0].length() != 0) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("copy_file.csv");
........
```

But I found no way to write a new csv file with the data of `List<String[]> lines`. I'm pretty sure it's possible but there's no **enough appropriate documentation**. In short, I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the front page of the official documentation:

```
CsvWriter.CsvWriterDSL<String[]> dsl = CsvWriter.from(String[].class)
                                                .columns("a[0]", "a[1]", "a[2]")
                                                .skipHeaders();

try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
    CsvWriter<String[]> writer = dsl.to(fileWriter);
    lines.forEach(CheckedConsumer.toConsumer(writer::append));
}
```

I assumed that each `String[]` has at least three elements - `columns("a[0]", "a[1]", "a[2]")`. Otherwise, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will occur.

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1, updated the answer. add `skipHeaders()` while defining a dsl

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1, you might generate that `String[] columns` on the fly knowing the length of the longest array in your list

Answer (score 2):

After a **discussion with the library's author**, it appears that the ideal code for this case is to use `CsvCellWriter` (when we don't know in advance the number of columns to write, in fact if we don't have the header) instead of `CsvWriter` because `CsvWriter` needs to know in advance the structure of the csv file to write; **lines** is a `List<String[]>`

The Maven dependency:

```
<groupId>org.simpleflatmapper</groupId>
<artifactId>sfm-csv</artifactId>
<version>3.18.3</version>
```

---

```
import org.simpleflatmapper.csv.*;
import org.simpleflatmapper.csv.impl.writer.CsvCellWriter;
..........
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new_file.csv");
CsvCellWriter cellWriter = CsvCellWriter.DEFAULT_WRITER.separator(',').quote('"');
lines.forEach ( strs ->  {
try {
    if (strs.length > 0) {
        cellWriter.writeValue(strs[0], writer);
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
           cellWriter.nextCell(writer);
           cellWriter.writeValue(strs[i], writer);
        }
       }
    cellWriter.endOfRow(writer);
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
} );
writer.close();
```

This code allows to write identically the data of the list because we can chose the separator, the quote and eventually other options. **Moreover** this library seems to be convenient and quick enough to parse csv files.